# How to convert this SQL query to Linq to Entity query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

could you help me please convert this SQL query to Linq to Entity query? Thank you

```
select distinct item, count(item) as count 
from TableName 
where ColumnName = @parameter and (ColumnName2 = @parameter2 OR ColumnName3 = @parameter3)
group by item  order by item asc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from TableName in db.TableName
where TableName.Column1 == 'param1' 
    && ( TableName.Column2 == 'param2' || TableName.Column3 == 'param3' )
group item by new { TableName.Item } into t
orderby t.Key.Item
select new {  t.Key.Item,  ItemCount = t.Count() }
```

Comment: Thank you, that works but only for one parameter, how can I accomplish using 2 parameters  (ColumnName2 = @parameter2 OR ColumnName3 = @parameter3)

Comment: @George - I've updated the query in my post. In general, you would use similar boolean logic as you would in your SQL query except you would use `&&` for AND and `||` for OR.

Comment: ok one more question. if I need to select one of the parameter which doesn't have a null value. How do I need to change the query?

Comment: @George - Can you amend your question to illustrate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you. I found work around for my case. Your solution in general works for me.

Comment: @George - If that is the case, then it is customary to mark an answer and provide an up vote.